# Git SSH Not Working after installing new Dev Shell

Tags: ssh, git

I have carefully followed the document [go/dev-shell](https://dev-shell.gaiacloud.jpmchase.net/#/index#intellijconfiguration) to install the new dev shell and Git Setup on LVDI3. When I run the ds sync, I got the error message:

```
git@bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I run the following two commands to check the configuration.

```
$ ssh-add -l
error fetching identities: agent refused operation
```

```
$ ssh -vT v684780@bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net [147.107.136.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net:22 as 'v684780'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256                                                                     
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256                                                           
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none                      
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none                      
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY                                                                      
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:U1WSHx08ejrFmnHhLOyTO6krz1ufthX3VNxKRKh1yjg                
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                                    
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @                                                    
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                                    
The ECDSA host key for bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net has changed,                                     
and the key for the corresponding IP address 147.107.136.129                                                   
is unknown. This could either mean that                                                                        
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host                                                       
and its host key have changed at the same time.                                                                
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                                    
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @                                                    
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                                                    
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!                                                          
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!                                    
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.                                                     
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is                                                   
SHA256:U1WSHx08ejrFmnHhLOyTO6krz1ufthX3VNxKRKh1yjg.                                                            
Please contact your system administrator.                                                                      
Add correct host key in /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.                          
Offending ECDSA key in /c/Users/v684780/.ssh/known_hosts:2                                                     
ECDSA host key for bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net has changed and you have requested strict checking.  
Host key verification failed.
```

I googled the web, someone suggested to remove the cached key, or update the C:\Users\v684780.ssh\known_hosts. I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The key line in the message is

```
The ECDSA host key for bitbucketdc-cluster03-ssh.jpmchase.net has changed,
```

Thus the host you try to connect to has changed its identity. One solution is indeed to either delete the file where your host keys are stored or - better - open it in a simple text editor such as notepad and remove only the line concerning the 'offending' host. It is a plain text file with a special format of one line per pair of host, algorithm and key, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

However! Please make sure that you check the identity of the host before you re-add it so that you do not fall prey to an actual attacker who modified the target host.